# feof(): supplied resource is not a valid stream

Tags: php

```
function numOfLines () {
    $file = fopen("data/text.txt", "r");
    $count = 0;
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
print_r(numOfLines());  = output 13 (for example)
```

Above code works perfectly fine.

However, if I declare $FILE variable outside the function and pass it as parameter of the function, then it gives this error "feof(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource "

```
$FILE = fopen("data/text.txt", "r");
function numOfLines ($file) {
    
    $count = 0;
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file, 1024);
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
print_r(numOfLines($FILE)); = feof(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource
```

Could anyone explain it a little bit what's actually going on here?

Comment: Your code is working. Note: you are not checking the return value from `fopen()` for file open failures. Which version of PHP? What are you leaving out of your question that could generate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring **$FILE** as the file handle, but passing the undefined **$file** as an argument to the function. PHP is case sensitive.

Comment: Where do you see that? The function call is `numOfLines($FILE);`. The function declaration should use a different variable name otherwise you will get warnings.

Comment: Ah, you're right; as I was looking I got the definition and the call jumbled in my mind. Mind John, not me.

Comment: Extra eyes sometimes help.